# Pointer and structure of structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have this definitions of my structures:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[100];//the probleme is here
    char type[100];//and here
    int quantity;
} product;

typedef struct{
    int dim;
    product produs[100];
} ceva1;

typedef struct{
    int dim;
    ceva1 produs[1000];
} ceva;
```

In main i have this code:

```
int main(){
    ceva *pointer,obiect;
    pointer=&obiect;
    test1(pointer)
    obiect.dim=0;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this program, I get an error saying "c.exe has stoped working".
I've seen that, if I remove objiet the error will dissapear but I have a function and when I call that function the error appears again. What's wrong?

```
void test1(ceva *pointer){
pointer->produs[0].produs[0].quantity=1;
```

}

Comment: You've declared 100,000 structures, each of which has 200 characters in it, resulting in *at least* 2,000,000 bytes of consumed automatic variable space. Whats the name of this website?

Comment: here: test1(pointer) missing a semicolon ";"

Comment: If you remove the obiect then pointer is pointing nowhere so it's logical that it will not work. Trying malloc the pointer first and then run the program again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's note that `sizeof(ceva) > 20000000`, so you're likely running out of stack space. Instead, you can allocate the data on the heap:

```
int main(){
    ceva *data = malloc(sizeof(ceva));
    test1(data);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ceva` structure takes up over 20MB of space. That's probably a lot more than the available space you have on the stack, which commonly results in a crash at runtime (a stackoverflow)

Allocate it dynamically instead:

```
int main(){
    ceva *pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);
...
```